# Why do the leaves of my new Chinese Evergreen turn yellow even if I wait 5 weeks between watering?

Tags: diagnosis

Is there any way to tell when a Chinese evergreen really  needs watering?  After maintaining a  Chinese evergreen for 24 years, it died of old age. This plant taught me to wait till it drooped before watering it. That usually took about 2 weeks. 
I now have a new one. After the first month, it did not seem to droop at all,so I watered it anyway.Seveal leaves turned yellow within days. I waited 5  weeks. More leaves yellowed.
I now wait till the plant droops; this takes at least a 5 to 6 weeks.  But by then the plant feels very very dry.
When I do water it even after that long time, a few leaves turn yellow.
HOw on earth does one manage Chinese evergreen so that it maintains its life and beauty?

Comment: LUL just dont touch it basically ever and it will "maintain its life and beauty" sounds to me like you are looking for a plant which requires more participation! When you do water it, just mist the leaves don't dump water on the soil.

Comment: After you got the plant home, did you transfer it to another, larger pot? Does the pot its in have drainage holes? A photo would be helpful...

Comment: I never could grow those. They seemed disease prone. Do you have a picture?